# GPT repair on EDL Mode deleted all partitions and bricked the phone

Tags: recovery-mode, partitions

How could I repair broken GPT on bricked Android?

GPT eMMC disk is not detected by the computer. In other words, the GPT disk is not detected normally because all its partitions have been deleted.

[image: GPT TABLE BLANK DELETED ALL PARTITIONS falsely]

[image: my block device in linux]

How to detect emmc-utils in EDL Mode? How do I fix GPT disk in EDL Mode?

Comment: you know you can't run `lsblk` on phone this way, don't you?